# Could not find a match for 'new[](unsigned int,undefined,const char *,int)' Full parser context

Tags: c++, file, error-handling

```
 ifstream FileName;
       FileName.open(rootFilePath, ios::in);

       if (!FileName) {
           return 0;
       }
       else {
            std::string result, searchstr, specialch, libUri, str, output;
            int length;
            size_t startpos, posspec1st, posspec2nd;

            FileName.seekg(0, ios::end);
            length=FileName.tellg();
            FileName.seekg(0, ios::beg);

            char* Filecontent = new char[length+1];
            FileName.read(Filecontent,length);
            result = Filecontent;
            searchstr="LIBRARY_FILE";
            specialch = "\"";
            startpos=result.find(searchstr);
            posspec1st =result.find(specialch,startpos);
            posspec2nd = result.find(specialch,posspec1st+1);
            libUri = result.substr(posspec1st,posspec2nd-posspec1st);
            str = "file:/";
            output=libUri.replace(str.find(str),str.length()+1,"");

            delete []Filecontent;
       }
```

This is my code i am getting the above error if i run this in a specific path

If i try to run this in another place its working but in specfic place its showing the error.

Comment: Can you explain in more detail? I assume it is a runtime error, are you seeing it in the debugger? Perhaps make this a [mcve] as well.

Comment: i saw this error while debugging the code.

Comment: i am using builder exe

Comment: What is builder.exe? When it crashes in the debugger use the call stack to find where in your code the crash starts. If you examine the variables you may figure out why as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have a general problem in your code with checking return codes or status of IO operations.

But first I strongly recommend to rename variable "FileName" to "fileStream". This is a stream and not the name of the file.

Then for each IO operation, please check, if the operation failed or not.

You can do the with `if (!fileStream) { /* Do some error handling */ }`

Regarding your mentioned bug. It is hard to judge, because there is not enough context.

My guess is that the problem will come from the `substr` function. As you can read [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr):

> The returned string is constructed as if by basic_string(data()+pos, count), which implies that the returned string's allocator will be default-constructed — the new allocator might not be a copy of this->get_allocator().

And the cuase for that could be some strange parameters, when you call the function.

The problem is again that you do not check the return code of the function `find`. It could return `std::string::npos` Please modify the code and add the checks for the function return codes. And then do the needful.